# Создание объекта из виртуального класса

Tags: ооп, c++

Здравствуйте,

Я пишу программу, исходный код который можно посмотреть и скомпилировать здесь. http://goo.gl/InB8B6. Если вы попробуете скомпилировать её по ссылке, то получите ошибку.

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':                   
> main.cpp:42:8: error: cannot declare variable 'sh' to be
>  of abstract type 'Shape'                             
>   Shape sh;

Некоторые детали:

- `Shape` абстрактный класс фигуры
- `Canvas` класс холста. Метод `add()` возвращает указатель на фигуру. И далее можно у этой фигуры выполнять методы. Например: `shape->draw()`, `shape->hide()`

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться как исправить код так, чтобы:

1. Можно было создать объект класса `Shape`
2. Можно было корректно выполнять `Canvas::add()` и запоминать указатель на фигуру

---

Для удобства вынесу сюда фрагменты кода:

**Shape.h**

```
#pragma once

using namespace std;

class Shape {
public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
    virtual void hide() = 0;
    virtual ~Shape() {}

};
```

**Line.h** (один из наследников Shape)

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"
#include <math.h>
#include "Shape.h"

using namespace std;

class Line : public Shape {
public:
    Line();
    Line(Point a, Point b);
    virtual void draw();
    virtual void hide();
    void move(Point da, Point db);
    void setA(Point a);
    Point getA();
    void setB(Point B);
    Point getB();
    float len();
protected:
    Point a;
    Point b;
};

Line::Line() {
    Point a, b;
    Line(a, b);
}

Line::Line(Point a, Point b) {
    this->a = a;
    this->b = b;
}

void Line::draw() {
    cout << "����� "<< a.print() <<"-"<< b.print() << " ����������" << endl;
}

void Line::hide() {
    cout << "����� " << a.print() << "-" << b.print() << " ������" << endl;
}

void Line::move(Point da, Point db) {
    this->hide();
    a += da;
    b += db;
    this->draw();
}

// ...
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.h"
#include "Line.h"
#include "Triangle.h"
#include "Quadrangle.h"
#include "Pentagon.h"
#include "Ellipse.h"
#include "Circle.h"
#include "Canvas.h"

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    Point c2a(0, 0);
    Point c2b(1, 0);
    Point c2c(1, 2);
    Point c2d(0, 2); 
    Point c2e(1, 0);

    Canvas cnv;
    Shape sh;
    //sh = cnv.add(c2a);
    //sh->draw();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Отвечу на первый вопрос - нельзя создать объект абстрактного класса.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Абстрактный_класс

Comment: @A1essandro, я прикрепил код к вопросу. Я надеюсь, что достаточно понятно описал идею. Вы можете подсказать как это реализовать правильно? Я мог бы ответить на вопросы, если что-то непонятно.

Comment: @ssh извините за нескромный вопрос, а вы сами писали этот код?

Comment: @DreamChild, да

Comment: @ssh тогда рецепт прост - юзайте указатели на классы. Впрочем, @fori1ton уже все объяснил куда подробнее

Comment: Мне кажется, что Hide() напрасно объявлена виртуальной. Просто, она должна исполнять Shape->Draw() в моде NotXor, но тогда и рисовать следует в этой моде.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Строка

```
Shape sh;
```

является неявным созданием объекта класса `Shape` посредством вызовом его конструктора по умолчанию. Но класс `Shape` абстрактный, поэтому попытка создать его экземпляр выльется в ошибку компиляции. Если вы не хотите, чтобы объект создавался сразу при объявлении, используйте указатели вместо ссылок:

```
Shape* sh;
sh = cnv.add(c2a);
sh->draw();
```

Теперь неявное создания объекта не происходит, вместо него происходит присвоение указателя на неабстрактный класс-наследник указателю на абстрактный класс-родитель, что является корректрным кодом.

Почитайте подробнее про отличия ссылок и указателей в C++.